# Get all attributes of a class in Python

Tags: python, class, object, attributes

Is it possible to get all attributes of some class or object? I have a class with many attributes and I want to make a function/method which returns all attributes of object equals to None.

Since there is many of these attributes I have to avoid writing all of them into the function.

Something like this:

```
def get_all_empty_attributes(self):
    for attr  in self.attributes.names:
        if self.attr==None:
            yield attr
```

Is it possible to do using builtin functions?

Comment: You can, as in the answer below but perhaps you should consider using a named tuple or just a dict if you have lots of key-value pairs which you want to iterate over and query dynamically instead of explicit attributes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `vars`

```
for property, value in vars(your_class).iteritems():
    print(property, ":", value)
```

Comment: Now just .items() in python 3.x